# How to post some datas to a url and redirect to it in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a bank gateway and I want to post some datas to a url and then redirect to that url.

How can I do it in asp.net mvc4 actionresult?

This is what I have tried:

```
public ActionResult Gateway(int orderId)
{
    var order = orderRepo.GetOrder(orderId);
    if (order.SiteUserId != SessionContext.GetSiteUserData().SiteUserId)
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "کد سفارش نا معتبر می باشد.";
        return View();
    }
    string merchantCode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MerchantCode"].ToString();
    string terminalCode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TerminalCode"].ToString();
    string redirectAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectAddress"].ToString();
    string PrivateKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PrivateKey"].ToString();
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (var orderItem in order.OrderItems)
    {
        sum += orderItem.Price;
    }
    string amount = sum.ToString();
    string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    string invoiceDate = order.CreateDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    string invoiceNumber = order.OrderId.ToString();
    string ActionIs = "1003";
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.FromXmlString(PrivateKey);
    string data = "#" + merchantCode + "#" + terminalCode + "#" + invoiceNumber +
          "#" + invoiceDate + "#" + amount + "#" + redirectAddress + "#" + ActionIs + "#" + timeStamp + "#";
            byte[] signedData = rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), new
    SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
    string signedString = Convert.ToBase64String(signedData);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://pep.shaparak.ir/gateway.aspx"); 
    byte[] textArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signedString);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = textArray.Length;
    request.GetRequestStream().Write(textArray, 0, textArray.Length);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return Redirect("https://pep.shaparak.ir/gateway.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Cant you just redirect after posting the data like using Redirect('url');